# How to create a loop using querySelector

Tags: javascript, html

Well, I had an idea, starting a html tag with a value of 1. And then using the browser console, assigning an id to the tag, and using the querySelector method to change the tag's value, it works perfectly.

However, I would like to create a loop on the console, to make this value 1 go up to 100, is it possible to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS Loop's</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I start a loop on the console, and make this `p` tag start a count and stop at 100?

**EDIT**

I said it `works perfectly`, because I changed the tag value, with querySelector, the code I used was this

```
document.querySelector("p").innerHTML = "Changed"
```

I assigned the value *Changed*, but I would like to know if it is possible to start a repeat loop and start a count from 1 to 100

Comment: Is it possible to assign the function querySelector, a function as a value, and make this function run the loop?

Comment: `it works perfectly` ... Where is this perfectly working code in your question? You tag `javascript` but only show `html`.

Comment: `create a loop on the console` what does it mean...???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger the loop in this case by entering `increment()` into the console.

```js
var incrementer = document.querySelector("#incrementer");
function increment(){
  var current = incrementer.textContent;
  if(current!=100){
    incrementer.textContent=parseInt(current)+1;
    setTimeout(increment, 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS Loop's</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="incrementer">1</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Automatic example:

```js
var incrementer = document.querySelector("#incrementer");
function increment(){
  var current = incrementer.textContent;
  if(current!=100){
    incrementer.textContent=parseInt(current)+1;
    setTimeout(increment, 10);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>JS Loop's</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="incrementer">1</p>
    <button onclick="increment();">Increment</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will loop until you reach the desired number. I made it 10, but 100 will work too. Note of caution: the "++" will trigger a warning in JS Lint.

```js
function addOne() {
    "use strict";

    //Get "p" tag.
    const tag = document.querySelector("p");

    //Assign an id (not needed, but you wanted to).
    tag.id = "your-id";

    //Get the text content (1).
    let count = tag.textContent;

    //Loop, stop when condition false.
    while (count <= 10) {
        console.log(tag.textContent = count);
        count++;
    }
}

addOne();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var incrementer = document.querySelector("#incrementer");
var inter = setInterval(function() {
  var current = parseInt(incrementer.textContent);
  while (current <= 100) {
    current++;
    incrementer.textContent=current;
  }
  clearInterval(inter);
}, 10);
```